# My laptop can't identify my home network, what do I do?

Tags: windows-xp

One day i go on my laptop, and it doesn't connect to the internet because the home network is unidentified. I've tried all kinds of things to fix the problem, but nothing works. One of the error message that comes up when I try something is that the home network is hidden, or that the settings I have saved do not match the settings of the router. I've have now come to the conclusion that it is my laptop. Every other device in the house (other computers, Wii, Xbox, and my sister who has just recently returned from N.J. with her laptop) connects fine. What could be any of the possible problems with why my laptop cannot connect?

Comment: How old is your laptop? Your network card may not support the newest W-LAN standards that may be used by your router.

Comment: First thing to try would be to go somewhere else where there's a public wireless network and see if you can connect.  If not, then double-check that the "radio" is actually turned on.  If the laptop connects elsewhere, try rebooting the router.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the network from the list of 'known networks' and re-adding it? Something may have somehow corrupted itself which is disallowing you to connect. If this doesn't work, I would consider re-installing the wireless nic driver for your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Typical starting points, once you've identified a possible issue with a single computer is to remove variables:
Try updating drivers.
Try running virus scans.
Try using a different wireless management (if your device has its own proprietary software, try using it).
Uninstall and reinstall your wireless device.
Try it with a different wireless device.
Try it with the same wireless device on different wireless networks.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I would look at first.
Is your laptop picking up a correct IP address? Is it in the same range as your router?
Have you tried setting the IP address to a static address and see if it connects ok?
Have you been able to access the wireless with the laptop before, if so what changed?
Do you have any networking software installed i.e proxy software, vpn software etc. I once saw a laptop unable to pick up the wireless network due to a program called greenbow, as soon as that software was removed the wireless worked fine.

Addition : Have you tried plugging the laptop in directly and seeing if you can connect that way?